# Use of undefined constant 'lte' error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I trying to use asset helper in Laravel, but returned error:

> undefined constant

Here's my code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css) }}">
```

PS : lte is a directory which the css and js are placed

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: It indicates the error is located at this line?

Comment: yes sir, the error in on this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asset()` helper need path of assets as string so it will be

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css') }}">
```

`asset('path')` here `'` is important

for more info you can check official doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset